# How to restrict Website to Open Only from Authenticated IP adress

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, saas

I am working on My SAAS based application where I am facing one problem related to
requirement ,  my Application should be open from authenticated system only ,and it should be based on IP address. I will give permission from my database which IP address is authenticated. and It will work accordingly .. I have not tried any code because I have no Idea about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with an attribute that implements the `IAuthorizationFilter` interface.  This will get called during the authorization checks done on each request.

For instance:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class IPFilterAttribute : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    /// <summary>Invoked during authization checks for page load</summary>
    /// <param name="filterContext">Context of call, contains request and so on</param>
    public virtual void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        var request = filterContext?.HttpContext?.Request;
        if (request == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(filterContext));

        if (!CheckIPAddress(request.UserHostAddress))
            // Setting the Result property on filterContext stops processing.
            filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult("Address Forbidden");
    }

    /// <summary>Check if the supplied IP address is authorized to access this page</summary>
    /// <param name="addr">Client address to test</param>
    /// <returns>True if address is authorized, else false</returns>
    private bool CheckIPAddress(string addr)
    {
        // sample, just check if it's the localhost address
        return (addr == "127.0.0.1" || addr == "::1");
    }
}
```

This will check if the client address is localhost (`127.0.0.1` or `::1`) and allow it through, blocking everything else.  Adjust that as necessary.

In the `OnAuthorization` method, setting `filterContext.Result` will stop further processing.  In this case I use it to show a `403 - Forbidden` response.  You could also use a `RedirectResult` or some other result object.

You can attach that to a specific method or onto your controller class:

```
// Put this here to apply to all pages in this controller
[IPFilter]
public class TestController : Controller
{
    // Or here to only affect the index page
    [IPFilter]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```